# Why am I getting SCSS errors after updating to Ionic 4.5.0?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic4

I updated Ionic to the latest version, 4.5.0, and I'm getting this error:

```
 ERROR in ./src/theme/variables.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/theme/variables.scss)
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
[ng] BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
[ng]     at unknownQuery (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:129:10)
[ng]     at C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:187:11
[ng]     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
[ng]     at resolve (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:136:18)
[ng]     at browserslist (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:252:16)
[ng]     at Browsers.parse (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:66:12)
[ng]     at new Browsers (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:48:26)
[ng]     at loadPrefixes (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:85:20)
[ng]     at plugin (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:96:20)
[ng]     at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:295:14)
[ng]     at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:208:26)
[ng]     at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:221:14)
[ng]     at C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:213:17
[ng] ERROR in ./src/global.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/global.scss)
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
[ng] BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
[ng]     at unknownQuery (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:129:10)
[ng]     at C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:187:11
[ng]     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
[ng]     at resolve (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:136:18)
[ng]     at browserslist (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:252:16)
[ng]     at Browsers.parse (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:66:12)
[ng]     at new Browsers (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:48:26)
[ng]     at loadPrefixes (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:85:20)
[ng]     at plugin (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:96:20)
[ng]     at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:295:14)
[ng]     at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:208:26)
[ng]     at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:221:14)
[ng]     at C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:213:17
[ng] ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.page.scss
[ng] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
[ng] BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
[ng]     at unknownQuery (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:129:10)
[ng]     at C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:187:11
[ng]     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
[ng]     at resolve (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:136:18)
[ng]     at browserslist (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:252:16)
[ng]     at Browsers.parse (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:66:12)
[ng]     at new Browsers (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:48:26)
[ng]     at loadPrefixes (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:85:20)
[ng]     at plugin (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:96:20)
[ng]     at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:295:14)
[ng]     at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:208:26)
[ng]     at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:221:14)
[ng]     at C:\Users\Feaxer\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:213:17
[ng]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ng] ERROR in ./ansi-html 1:0
[ng] Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
[ng] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[ng] > #!/bin/sh
[ng] | basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
[ng] |
```

Ionic:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.5.0 (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.17
angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.10.7
angular-devkit/schematics : 7.0.7
angular/cli : 7.0.7
ionic/angular-toolkit : 1.2.0
```

System:

```
NodeJS : v10.14.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.4.1
OS : Windows 10
```

Why am I getting this error?

I've also started [a thread on the Ionic forums.](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-doesnt-work/150472)

Comment: I've edited out the image of the error and included the text here instead. It's best not to link to images, especially images of text such as code or stack traces.

Comment: It looks like this might be a viable workaround for you: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/issues/266